# How to parse HTML from URL with space?

Tags: iphone, html, objective-c

I use hpple to parse html from URL that I got from the rss feed that contains the space inside. I try to parse html by copying and pasting the url from browser and it works but when i do the same thing with the url that I got from rss feed, it seem doesn't work. I think the problem is space inside url, am I right? How do I parse HTML from that URL?

Many thanks

Comment: 'Unable to parse' but when i copy url directly from website it work fine

Comment: Fetching data from a URL and parsing what you get back are two separate operations.  If there is a problem with the URL, then that part will fail.  If you got back some HTML to give to hpple then there is no problem with the URL.  Suggest you step through with the debugger and figure out which bit is failing, then come back and we can probably help more with more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try escaping the URL.

```
NSString *url = [@"http://example.com/url with a space/" stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```